# How to correctly set the state of the progress bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have the following code to use `LinearProgressIndicator`:

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController) {

  val viewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModel>()

  val progress by viewModel.progress.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

  Text(text = "$progress")

  // Omit the code related to LinearProgressIndicator
}

@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val hotHubRepository: HotHubRepository): ViewModel(){
  val progress = flow {
    for(i in 0 .. 1000){
      // Simulate here are some time-consuming network requests
      delay(200)
      emit(i)
    }
  }.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = 0
  )
}
```

As soon as the user enters the `HomeScreen`, the progress bar starts, which is not what I expected.

What I expected is that the progress bar starts to start when the user takes some action, not automatically. Strictly speaking, it is expected that the task will be started manually by the user, but now the startup process is bound to the startup Flow.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have designed something, lets try and review to reach final solution

As we dealing with states we can thing about an initial state for Progress such as `Idle`. Then once button click or Action occured from compose we can call `updateProgress` so the state gets updated.

```kotlin
sealed interface UiState {
    object Idle : UiState

    data class Loading(
            val progress: Int,
        ) : UiState

        data class Error(
                val throwable: Throwable? = null,
            ) : UiState
        }

class VM : ViewModel() {

    private val _userFlow = MutableStateFlow<UiState>(UiState.Idle)
    val userFlow: StateFlow<UiState> = _userFlow.asStateFlow()

    fun updateProgress() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            flow {
                for (i in 0 until 10) {
                    delay(1000)
                    emit(i)
                }
            } .collect {
                value ->
                _userFlow.update {
                    when (value) {
                        0 -> UiState.Idle
                        else -> UiState.Loading(value)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In compose

```kotlin
val progress by viewModel.userFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
if (progress is UiState.Loading) {
    Text(text = "${(progress as UiState.Loading).progress}")
}
```

Comment: much obliged. Sage